# Where to declare CList in Visual MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have 2 class: Class1(class1.cpp and class1.h) and Class2 (class2.cpp and class2.h), in Class2 I need to add elements to CList (AddHead, AddTail....), and in Class1 I need show CList. I don't know where I should declare CList `CList<myClass, myClass&> myList;`, when I declare it in Class 1, Class 2 don't know myList('myList' : undeclared identifier), when I declare it in Class 2, Class 1 also don't know myList to show?

Answer (score 0):

Where you should declare it depends on the lifetime it should have, to make sure it will not get destroyed while the other class still needs access to it.

If you declare it in Class1 then Class2 will need to #include "class1.h" and it will need to be initialized with a pointer to the Class1 object or to the CList. It must save and use that pointer to access the CList.

EDIT:
Since myList is a member of Class1 it can only be accessed with a pointer or reference to a Class1 object, not as a variable all by itself.  Here Class1 would pass a pointer to itself ('this') when constructing a Class2:

```
void Class2::Class2(Class1* p1)
{  
   INT_PTR size = p1->myList.GetSize();
```

Comment: Hi, could you please give me an example? I have done include "class1.h" but it said "'myList' : undeclared identifier

Comment: See my edit. If that doesn't help you enough then you will need to show all your code that declares and uses (or attempts to use) myList. There are a lot of ways to do it wrong and we can't guess here what you did.